# Solving question by binomial probability

Tags: probability

If, over a given period in Brisbane, rain falls at random on 4 days of every 10, find the probability that the first 2 days of a given week will be wet and the remainder of the week fine.

using the formula $(nCx)(p^x)((p')^{n-x})$

I put n=10, x=2, p=0.4, p'=0.6

and I got 0.12, but the actual answer is 0.012.

Comment: The wrong formula is being used. You probably in fact took $n=5$. Then your formula gives the probability that there were a total of $2$ wet days and $3$ dry, not necessarily in the required sequence WWDDD.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not need to use the formula for the binomial distribution. Just calculate the first two days are rainy and the following 5 days are fine:

$p^2\cdot (1-p)^5$

The days, which are rainy and the days which are fine, are fixed.

Comment: you are right! what was i thinking... haha thanks